# Are consequences tracked per stress track?

Tags: dresden-files, stress, consequences

When taking too much stress, one can take consequences. However, can one - at the same time - have both a mental and physical consequence of the same level or is there only a single 'pool' of consequences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Normally No

You can fill your normal (free) Consequence slots with *either* consequence type, but only one Consequence per slot. If if one of those is filled with, say, ***Deep Cuts***, you *can't* also fill it with ***Spooked*** or the like, as it is already filled.

However, some skills give you *special, extra* slots. Those can only be used to absorb Consequences of the appropriate type (*not* just any type). The fifth level of Conviction grants you an extra Mild Consequence slot that can *only* be used to absorb a Mental Consequence (incidentally, it *also* gives you mental-only Stress Boxes at first and third level); the fifth level of Endurance works the same for Physical ones. But you can have multiple *types of these slots* if you achieve high levels in multiple slot-granting skills.

So if you somehow end up having fifth levels of both Endurance and Conviction, you now have: your 'universal', free Severe, Moderate and Mild boxes (of which each can be used for *one* consequence of any time when you need it), a bonus Physical Mild box that can only be used for physical ones, *and* a bonus Mental Mild box that can only be used for mental ones.

Comment: Could you give an example of one of these skills?

Comment: @WeckarE. - The other one is Endurance, which gives you Physical stress boxes and an extra Mild Physical slot.